# Determining P(ABC) if we are given P(AB) and P(BC) where A and C are mutually exclusive events.

Tags: probability

Since A and C are mutually exclusive events, we know that $P(AC) = 0$. Thus we know $P(AB)$, $P(AC)$, $P(BC)$. But I'm not sure how I can figure out $P(ABC)$ from this.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Note that $ABC$ is a subevent of $AC$. Draw a Venn diagram to confirm that there is no point at which A,B,C all coincide

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive events, then $A\cap C = \emptyset$.

It follows then that $A\cap B\cap C = (A\cap C)\cap B = \emptyset \cap B = \emptyset$ and so $Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=Pr(\emptyset)=0$

Comment: Then, $P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C) + P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - 0 - P(B\cap C) + 0 = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(B\cap C)$ ?

Comment: Yes$~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Follow up: If I have to determine the probability of $A\cup B \cap C$, how would I go about this. I have $P(A\cup B)$, but I don't know if $A\cup B$ and D are independent events or not. Drawing a van diagram shows me that $A\cup B \cap C$ is $B\cap C$, but how can I show this without drawing one?

Comment: $A\cup B\cap C$ is ambiguous and doesn't mean anything until fixed.  Do you mean $(A\cup B)\cap C$?  Or do you mean $A\cup (B\cap C)$.  These are two different things.

Comment: I meant$ (A\cup B)\cap C$

Comment: $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ which by our assumption, $A\cap C=\emptyset$ so in this particular case you have $(A\cup B)\cap C = (B\cap C)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89460/discussion-between-thomas-formal-and-jmoravitz).